# Are X and |X| independent? where $f(x)=\exp(-|x|)/2$

Tags: probability

The density function of $X$ is $f(x)=\frac{e^{-|x|}}2, x\in(-\infty, +\infty)$. Are $X$ and $|X|$ independent?

My thought is: Let $Y=|X|$, so $f(y)=e^{-y},y\in(0,+\infty)$

Then try $P(X\le x,Y\le y)$, I cannot go further, can anyone help?

Edit:Thank you guys and please allow me to extend my question, is there a general way to determine the independence of 2 viriables when their joint distribution are not given?

Comment: For $x > 0$, $P(|X| \leq x, X \geq x) = 0 \neq P(|X| \leq x)P(X \geq x) > 0$, so no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $U$ and $V$ are independent, then $f(U)$ and $g(V)$ are independent. Let $U=X$, $V=|X|$, $f(t)=g(t)=|t|$.

Comment: Your answer is more extensive!

Comment: Yes, but definitely less concrete. There is much to be said for concrete.

Answer (score 4):

$P(|X|<1)$ and $P(X>1)$ are both positive, so if $X$ and $|X|$ were independent $P(|X|<1 \land X>1)$ would be positive too. But it is clearly zero, so they are not independent.